# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" если попытаться добавить число к списку `end += int(i)`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

```
x="234"
end=[]
for i in x:
    print i
    end+=int(i)#[1]
    print end
    end.reverse()
print end
```

[1]еще он говорит, что итератор не должен быть int. "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Он выводит

```
2
3
4
['4', '2', '3']
```

А должен он выводить 4,3,2

P.S: сама задача, которую я хочу проверить в питоне:
1) Любое число X (поставить диапазон)

2) отразить его зеркально (т.е. 123 = 321) минус X
`a=(x.reverse()-x)`

3)`b=a+a.reverse()`

В итоге по "фокусу" b должно всегда = **1089**

Comment: `x=int(str(x)[::-1])` !!!

Comment: Готово!
Видео на ютубе помогло.
`x=234;print x
inv_x=int(str(x)[::-1]);print inv_x
a=inv_x-x;print a
inv_a=int(str(a)[::-1]);print inv_a
b=a+inv_a;print b`

Comment: Старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос (можно несколько связанных вопросов задать, если несколько проблем с кодом есть). Не нужно многошаговое учебное задание целиком приводить -- это не очень полезно для будущих читателей.

Comment: Почему? Лично мне было бы интересно еще узнать историю возникновения вопроса (при желании). А если желания такого нету, то можно и не читать само ТЗ.

Comment: В общем случае, для контекста можно привести задание, но только в качестве фоновой информации, если на вопрос можно и так ответить (то есть если убрать описание задания, вопрос должен продолжать иметь смысл). В данном случае, описание задания только шум создаёт. Представьте человека, который получил TypeError и, не понимая откуда она взялась, приземлился на этой странице после запроса в web-поисковике—крайне вероятно, что такому человеку совершенно не интересно Ваше учебное задание, а интересно понять откуда TypeError взялась и как её исправить. Так один вопрос может нескольким людям  помочь.

Comment: Так я же написал ТЗ в P.S (которое не обязательно читать).
А решение этого вопроса я написал в ответе.
Никакого лишнего шума нету. =)
Спасибо за ответ в вопросе.

Answer (score 4):

`+=` на списках ожидает целую коллекцию, а не один элемент. Используйте `.append()`, чтобы добавить только один элемент:

```
>>> L = []
>>> L += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>>> L.append(1)
>>> L
[1]
>>> L += [2, 3]
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Готово!
Видео на youtube помогло.

```
x=234;print x
inv_x=int(str(x)[::-1]);print inv_x
a=inv_x-x;print a
inv_a=int(str(a)[::-1]);print inv_a
b=a+inv_a;print b
```

(с)thx https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1jdar3WADY